# R Shiny redirect to two URLs

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

The Shiny app below redirects to Google as soon as you press the button 'Submit'. I would like a similar app that redirects to two URLs (in sequence). So, for example it would go to "https://www.google.com" first and then to "https://www.stackoverflow.com". Is this possible?

```
library(shiny)

jscode <- "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('mymessage', function(message) { window.location = message;});"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(jscode)),
  actionButton("submit", "Submit")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
      url <- "https://www.google.com"
      session$sendCustomMessage("mymessage", url)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: No. This isn't specific to shiny at all. When you do a redirect, you no longer have any control over the user's browser. They have left your site and you can't make them go anywhere after that. Such a feature would be a security nightmare. One possible work around would be for your site to use iframes to include content from other websites. But that's a very different type of set up.

Answer (score 0):

```
jscode <- "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('redirect', function(URLS) {
  for (var i = 0; i < URLS.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.style.display = 'none';
      a.href = URLS[i];
      a.target = '_blank';
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      a.remove();
    }, i * 500);
  }
});"

  observeEvent(input$submit, {
      urls <- list("https://www.google.com", "https://www.stackoverflow.com")
      session$sendCustomMessage("redirect", urls)
  })
```