# shiny, redirect in a new tab/window

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I have a shiny app with a button, where when it is clicked it should redirect to a new URL, I have implemented the redirect, but it opens in the same window, how can I modify it such that the new URL is opened in either a new tab or new window?

```
library(shiny)

myjs <- "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('mymessage', function(message) {window.location= message ;});"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(myjs)),     
  actionButton("button", "Click me")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$button,{
    url <- "https://stackoverflow.com/"
    session$sendCustomMessage("mymessage", url)

    
  })
}
```

---

I tried it with

```
window.open
```

unfortunately, this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with an "a" element and a target blank to indicate you want to open in a new tab.

```
library(shiny)

myjs <- "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('mymessage', function(message) {
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.style.display = 'none';
      a.href = message;
      a.target = '_blank';
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      a.remove();
});"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(myjs)),     
  actionButton("button", "Click me")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$button,{
    url <- "https://stackoverflow.com/"
    session$sendCustomMessage("mymessage", url)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I got this from a similar (but not identical) question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67522705/r-shiny-redirect-to-two-urls)